# Mostrar elemento hijo en hover del elemento padre

Tags: css, hover

Espero me puedan ayudar con esta duda que tengo en cuanto a CSS.

Verán, tengo mi elemento padre con un elemento hijo, el cual quiero aparecer cuando el *mouse* se posicione sobre el elemento padre.

El elemento hijo lo inicializo con una altura de `0px`, y al posicionarme sobre el padre cambio la altura del hijo, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de mostrar los elementos del hijo cuando haya alcanzado su altura máxima.

Ejemplo:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  background-color: #FFAB91;
  color: #424242;
}

.container:hover .show {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 80px;
}

.container:hover button {
  visibility: visible;
}

.show {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #D84315;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h5>Categoría 1</h5>
  <div class="show"><button>Ver +</button></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h5>Categoría 2</h5>
  <div class="show"><button>Ver +</button></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h5>Categoría 3</h5>
  <div class="show"><button>Ver +</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: He puesto tu código de jsfiddle en la pregunta.

Comment: No he entendido bien, en tu ejemplo se ve que ya hace lo que preguntas, no? Podrías ampliar más con una imagen sobre que te refieres o ser un poco más explicito con tu pregunta.

Comment: Genial amigo blonfu, muchas gracias. Edgar Gutiérrez, me referia a aparecer el botón q está en el div hijo cuando éste halla alcanzado los 80 px, en este caso, como se ve en el ejemplo de @Alejandro Gallardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si es lo que necesitas pero le agregue una clase btn al button y luego lo anime con keyframes y le puse un delay al botón de 0.6s a continuación te comparto el código.

```css
.container {
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   display: flex;
   align-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
   border: 1px solid #FFF;
   background-color: #FFAB91;
   color: #424242;
}

 .show {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #D84315;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}
  .container:hover .show{
    height: 80px;
  }
  
  .btn{
   animation-name: btn;
   transition-delay: 0.6s;
   visibility: hidden;
  }
  .container:hover .btn{
    visibility: visible;
  }
  @keyframes btn {
   0% {
    
    opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
    
    opacity: 1; 
   }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h5>Categoría 1</h5>
  <div class="show">
   <button class="btn">Ver +</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h5>Categoría 2</h5>
  <div class="show">
   <button class="btn">Ver +</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h5>Categoría 3</h5>
  <div class="show">
   <button class="btn">Ver +</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @AlejandroGallardo, **bienvenido a Satck Overflow**,  te recomiendo te pases por la [sección de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más como se debe [responder una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), como editar tus respuestas y el porqué no debes generar más de un post a la misma pregunta cuando ambas respuestas son dependientes una de la otra.

Comment: Yo lo veo igual, cual es la duda del OP? hasta ahora no entiedo.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo Alejandro, era a lo q me referia